# select first element in select menu which comes dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a select menu which is coming dynamic

```
<select id="mymenu">
  <option >select your choice</option>
  <option value="1">value 1</option>
  <option value="2">value 2</option>
  <option value="3">value 3</option>
  <option value="4">value 4</option>
</select>
```

the id i am giving. but this select menu is coming after a pages loads when i click on button through ajax. i need to select second option/ third option by default

the following code is not working for me as it is coming dynamically

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#mymenu').find('option:eq(1)').attr('selected', true);
  });
```

How to select first option when comes dynamically

Comment: To operate on DOM with dynamic content use jQuery.On()...

Comment: Your code works perfectly, you just have to call it after the dom is modified (after the ajax call) and not when the document is ready.

Comment: select the option on the ajax success callback

Answer (score 1):

The `.ready` function fires only on page load - you are expecting it to run constantly in the background, and fire on any change to the DOM; this won't happen. What you need to do, is to call your function again after the pages load.

Answer (score 0):

A more complicated solution for the current scenario is to attach an event listener to the DOM and check elements that are inserted onto the page. After a required element is detected, trigger an action on it.

Actually, this solution is not for the current example, but someone will probably need this for doing more complicated things:

```
// Listen for inserted nodes, checking if its needed one 
// and triggering needed action
$(document).bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(event) {
    var elm = $(event.target);
    if (elm.attr('id') == 'mymenu') {
        elm.find('option:eq(1)').attr('selected', true);
    }
});

// create select box
var select = $('<select>').attr('id', 'mymenu');
var option = $('<option>');
var option_values = {
    0: 'select your choice',
    1: 'value 1',
    2: 'value 2',
    3: 'value 3',
    4: 'value 4'
};
$.each(option_values, function(key, val) {
    $(select).append(option.clone(true).val(key).text(val));
});

// insert select box into DOM
$(document.body).append(select);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dnGEL/